# "npx create-react-app my app" command is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

```
**Purva@DESKTOP-SS7ERSC /cygdrive/c**
$ npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-r
t_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin
npm ERR! path C:\
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt
_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Purva\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-10T08_29_03_15
4Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried uninstalling the nodejs and then reinstalling it. But the same error keeps showing again and again.
I have checked the environment variables and in that , the user variables have the path(node related only) :

`C:\Users\Purva\AppData\Roaming\npm`

and the system variables have the paths:

`C:\Users\Purva\AppData\Roaming\npm`
`C:\Program Files\nodejs\`
`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`

Please help me with the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npx create-react-app@latest my-app
```

Comment: not helping, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

didn't work when i tried to create my first react app so i used yarn instead. Command

```
npm install --global yarn
```

installs yarn and then you can just perform command

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: by using this yarn command, the same error keeps on repeating(the one that occurred in the previous command)